# What are the risks of using toString to get the name of a function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, es5-compatiblity

Since ES5 doesn't support [`Function#name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name). I was looking for a way to emulate that functionality. While a lot of people recommend using [`Function#toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/tostring), others strongly advised against it.

So what are the risks of using the below code to get the name of a function?

```
if (!Object.hasOwnProperty(Function.prototype, "name")) {
  Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, "name", {
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: true,
    get: function() {
      var result = /function\s+([^\s(]+)/.exec(this.toString());
      return result ? result[1] : "";
    }
  });
}
```

Since ES5 doesn't support [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility), I don't really see when the where the risk lies.

Comment: You may wish to [change the regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9337047/) to account for the more unusual possible function names (most prominently, `$`). Maybe [`function\s+([^(\s]+) *\(`](https://regex101.com/r/SQ2gXR/1), since the Javascript syntax can be assumed to already be valid

Comment: @CertainPerformance Would something like`function\s+([^\s(]+)` work? My thinking is that any function that is being checked will already have a valid name, therefore the name's end should be at the index where a space (space, tab, new line ...) or `(` is found.

Comment: Sure, the trailing part of the match isn't necessary, it just feels a bit more solid

Comment: Just be sure to handle all (appropriate) cases from the [Examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/tostring) table. Particularly, `func.toString` doesn't always start with "function".

Comment: @georg It seems to me all ES5 compatible examples start with `function`

Comment: What do you need the name for? Because these names are completely unreliable in real code

Comment: @Thomas In what way are they unreliable? Is it because two or more functions can have the same name under different scopes?

Comment: For example, I use to minify my production builds -> all names are gone/changed to single characters. Then using currying, debouncing, memoization, ... and the names are gone, because it's not the same function anymore. I also had in mind that `Function#bind` would return a function without name; a quick test showed that it just prepends `"bound "+name` but I'd have to check wether that behaviour is defined in the spec. So imo. the names are nice to have when debugging, but in production you can not rely on them.

Comment: @Thomas I am mostly planning on using it as `({"Date":()=>{},"Array":()=>{}...}[item.constructor.name])();`

Comment: As long as you're only dealing with the built in classes. But I'd use a `Map` and reference `map.get(item.constructor)` instead of its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [ECMAScript 5.1 specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.2) says, the `toString` method returns a string that has the syntax of [*FunctionDeclaration*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-A.5):

> #### Function.prototype.toString ( )
>
> An implementation-dependent representation of the function is returned. This representation has the syntax of a *FunctionDeclaration*. Note in particular that the use and placement of white space, line terminators, and semicolons within the representation String is implementation-dependent.
>
> The `toString` function is not generic; it throws a **TypeError** exception if its **this** value is not a Function object. Therefore, it cannot be transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method.

*FunctionDeclaration* has the following syntax:

> ***FunctionDeclaration* :**
>
> **function** *Identifier* **(** *FormalParameterList*<sub>opt</sub> **) {** *FunctionBody* **}**
>
> ***FormalParameterList* :**
>
> *Identifier*
>   *FormalParameterList* **,** *Identifier*

And [*Identifier*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6) defined like:

> ***Identifier* ::**
>
> *IdentifierName* **but not** *ReservedWord*
>
> ***IdentifierName* ::**
>
> *IdentifierStart*
>   *IdentifierName IdentifierPart*
>
> ***IdentifierStart* ::**
>
> *UnicodeLetter*
>   **$**
>   **_**
>   **\** *UnicodeEscapeSequence*
>
> ***IdentifierPart* ::**
>
> *IdentifierStart*
>   *UnicodeCombiningMark*
>   *UnicodeDigit*
>   *UnicodeConnectorPunctuation*

#### Conclusion

Although it isn't a beautiful way to get the function name (but the **only way** in ES5), if you make it parse all of the possibilities listed above, it can work safely in ES5.

But the ES6 standard modified the specifications for `.toString()`, which implies more possible syntaxes, making it unsafe to use this method in it.

**So, use this method only in versions prior to ES6.**

Comment: Not sure if you are saying that my code will suffice, or if I need to alter it. If its the latter, could you give an example of a function declaration that would cause a problem?

Comment: @nickzoum Your code is OK now; but I've answered before your edit, according to [CertainPerformance's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58352293/what-are-the-risks-of-using-tostring-to-get-the-name-of-a-function/58352725?noredirect=1#comment103058616_58352293)